# Join a list of tuples

Tags: python, tuples, nested-lists

My code looks the following:

```
from itertools import groupby

for key, group in groupby(warnstufe2, lambda x: x[0]):

    for element in group:
        a = element[1:4]
        b = element[4:12]
        c = [a,b]
        print(c)
```

When I print (c) I get something like this:

```
[(a,b,c),(d,e,f)] 
[(g,h,i),(j,k,l)]
```

where a1=(a,b,c) and b1=(d,e,f) and a2=(g,h,i) and b2 = (j,k,l).
Of course there is a3... and b3... 
However, I need something like this:

```
[(a,b,c),(d,e,f),(g,h,i),(j,k,l)]
```

I already tried a for loop through c:

```
for item in c:
    list1 = []
    data = list1.append(item)
```

But this did not help and resulted in:

```
None
None
```

based on this link:
 https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2008-February/060321.html

I appears to be easy, but I am new to python and did not find a solution yet, despite a lot of reading.
I appreciate your help!

Comment: What is `warnstufe2`?

Comment: @Bhargav Rao : it is a table from a postgresql database

Comment: When you do `data = list.append(...)`, data will be None because `append` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Please give a minimal example for `warnstufe2` so people can actually test their answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
from itertools import groupby

result = []
for key, group in groupby(warnstufe2, lambda x: x[0]):
    for element in group:
        a = element[1:4]
        b = element[4:12]
        c = [a,b]
        result.append(c)

print (result)
```

Comment: This will create a nested list of lists of tuples. I think you meant `extend`

Comment: `result.append()` will have the exact same result the OP is currently observing. You'd need to to `result.extend()` to get the flat list he wants.

Comment: Thanks for you answers, but also with extend, the result is the same as before.

Comment: @Jane_Tandert well obviously if you just `print(c)`. But if you look at `result`, it's a flattened list.

Comment: @Jane_Tandert *sigh* editing the answer so at least the answer you accepted is correct.

Comment: @ Lukas Graf...sorry, I was in  a hurry the day before yesterday. Extend() is working too, giving me a flattened list. However, I wanted a list of list, so append() did the job for me. I changed it back. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 5):

Use [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and [list unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
>>> items = [[('a','b','c'),('d','e','f')], [('g','h','i'),('j','k','l')]]
>>>
>>> list(chain(*items))
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f'), ('g', 'h', 'i'), ('j', 'k', 'l')]
```